# How to access or create File objects using Mocha (NodeJS)?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mocha.js

I'm a beginner in JavaScript and am creating my first project. I made a File Upload program which works, and I am now adding unit tests. I am trying to test how my program handles various different types of files (valid and invalid CSV/JSON files). However, my FileUploadHandler is expecting a File object and Mocha, which uses NodeJS, does not have a File class, so I cannot call new File to create File objects to pass in.

I tried to make a bunch of files manually and then pass them into the Mocha unit tests by path but I do not know how to get them to be passed in as File objects. -- I looked it up and it seems that you cannot access File objects by path via JS so if this is the case, what is a way I can do my unit testing?

I hope this was clear but if not, I can further clarify. Please help and thank you so much

** my function that I want to test takes in a File object

Ex.

```
describe('File testing', function() {
    it('cannot process non csv/jsons', function() {
        let f = new File([""], "html_file.html");
        let tester = new FileUploadHandler(f);
        ## expecting error ##
    })
})
```

Answer (score 0):

In my implementation I use, `mocha` and `chai` to make expectations on desired inputs, here is an example of a failing test when user try to upload two files in one html form (this is not allowed by my multer rules, it is configured for single upload).

```
it('Check can not post more than 1 file', function(done) {
        api.post('/files')
            .set('Accept', 'application/json; charset=utf-8')
            .field('Content-Type', 'multipart/form-data')
            .field("sequence", 1)
            .field("media", 10)
            .attach("image", 'test/files/edit.png')
            .attach("image", 'test/files/edit.png')
            .expect(500)
            .end(function(err, res) {
                expect(res.status).to.equal(500);
                done();
            });
    });
```

I just declared my form inputs, and a field type called image, that is the data holder for the image.